# Visual Studio 2008 Debugger randomly dying

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7

I am having a rather bizarre error when trying to debug a .NET web application.

My system: Windows 7 Ultimate (IIS7), Visual Studio 2008, DotNetNuke 4.8.2.

I have a Web Application which I am trying to attach the debugger to w3wp.exe.  I set a breakpoint in my code: could be an ascx.cs page or a library I am referencing.

Here's the weird part.  Once I run through that part of the website, the code breaks, and I am able to debug, step through between 1-20 lines of code, and all of a sudden it's as if I pressed Continue.  The timing doesn't seem significant (sometimes it happens after 2 minutes, sometimes after 2 seconds) and there are no error messages in the output or Event Viewer.

If I try to attach the debugger with managed and native, it goes to disassembly mode for w3wp. Again, no real obvious error.

Anyone can at least point me in the right direction as to what could be interrupting the debugger?  Without any error messages, I cannot even begin to figure out where to go next.

I've tried:

- Rebuilding the website configuration in IIS
- Check the app pool settings to make sure it's not timing out
- disabled every conceivable service on my computer
- Resetting my Visual Studio settings
- Rebuilding the project

Comment: consider yourself lucky. I just get crashes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the VS2008 SP1 debugger. MS released a hotfix some time ago:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912

The bug is described on that page as:

> Stepping when you debug a managed
>   multithreaded application can randomly
>   turn into a "go"

Comment: Yup, that worked!  Question:  How did you know that? I swear I searched every conceivable term related via Google.

Comment: The URL appeared to me in a vision -- after smashing my head against the keyboard one too many times.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't do that enough